# MySql count entries without duplicate datetime

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table which logs all "check-ins" into a system. I want to count all "check-ins" from an user for the current day, but there's the problem that sometimes users check-in like two or three times by mistake in one minute. So I just want to count all entries with a gap from at least two minutes

My current command looks like:

```
"SELECT event_datetime, LEFT(tag_uid,8) AS tag_uid, count(*) as anzahl FROM events WHERE date(event_datetime) = curdate() GROUP BY tag_uid"
```

So I only want to count it if the gap between event_datetime is at least two minutes grouped by the tag_uid (the user)

Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to calculate the gap for each tag_uid and then you can set conditions as you wish. To calculate the gap you need to have a nested select commands which will get the "first checkIn" and "last checkIn" using min and max command. Use the "timediff" to calculate the time gap.

NOTE: i haven't tried the code, also I've added the select commands so you can see the values to find Errors.

the code would look similar to this:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_outer_events.event_datetime,
    LEFT(tbl_outer_events.tag_uid,8) AS tag_uid,
    count(tbl_outer_events.tag_uid) as anzahl,
    (select min(event_datetime) from tbl_events as T1 where ( (t1.tag_uid = tbl_outer_events.tag_uid)) and (date(t1.event_datetime) = curdate()) )as `first_checkin`,
    (select max(event_datetime) from tbl_events as T1 where ( (t1.tag_uid = tbl_outer_events.tag_uid)) and (date(t1.event_datetime) = curdate()))as `last_checkin`,
    (select TIMEDIFF(max(event_datetime), min(event_datetime)) from tbl_events as T1 where ( (t1.tag_uid = tbl_outer_events.tag_uid)) and (date(t1.event_datetime) = curdate())) as `interval`
FROM events as tbl_outer_events
WHERE ((date(event_datetime) = curdate())
        AND  (select TIMEDIFF(max(event_datetime), min(event_datetime)) from tbl_events as T1 where ( (t1.tag_uid = tbl_outer_events.tag_uid)) and (date(t1.event_datetime) = curdate())) >= '00:20:00')
GROUP BY tag_uid;
```

PS: please provide us with sample data or desired outcome. it will help us and you to understand the issue.